# Issue running selenium on M2, Chrome Driver crashs after start

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have tried this using both images:

- **seleniarm/standalone-chromium**
- **selenium/standalone-chrome:107.0**

With the result being the same

Right after the start, there's a log entry that doesn't seems to appear when the selenium is running fine:

```
2023-03-23 11:04:16 2023-03-23 15:04:16,651 INFO success: selenium-standalone entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 0 seconds (startsecs)
2023-03-23 11:04:16 find: '/home/seluser/.config/chromium/Crash Reports/pending/': No such file or directory
```

and then, when I try to access the selenium trought the application
it raises:

```
2023-03-23 13:29:00 17:29:00.712 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - Unable to create session: Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
2023-03-23 13:29:00   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
2023-03-23 13:29:00   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Full error log: [log file](https://gist.github.com/guilhermebferreira/6d766f19bd4a5070589037a8133af5a4)

ChromeDriver version **111.0.5563.64**

`selenium/standalone-chrome:107.0` seems to be stable to M1 users for some months so far
I have teammates running the same app on M1 with no issues
(Running using the same settings that we use for linux right now)

Does anyone know how to solve that?

Comment: try this one: docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome:111.0

Comment: @JamesRisner same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try using below docker image with the arm64 compatibility , had the same issue with using **selenium/standalone-chrome**
Instead use **seleniarm/standalone-chromium**

https://hub.docker.com/u/seleniarm

Run it with command

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 seleniarm/standalone-chromium
```

Solved it using comments mentioned in github here
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/1076#issuecomment-788343926

Comment: not sure what I did wrong the first time testing with this image, bug now it works